# How can I use Server-Sent events in Iron?

Tags: rust, iron

I have a small Rust application that receives some requests through a serial port, does some processing and saves the results locally. I wanted to use a browser as a remote monitor so I can see everything that is happening and as I understand SSEs are pretty good for that.

I tried using Iron for that but I can't find a way to keep the connection open. The request handlers all need to return a `Response`, so I can't keep sending data.

This was my (dumb) attempt:

```
fn monitor(req: &mut Request) -> IronResult<Response> {
    let mut headers = Headers::new();
    headers.set(ContentType(Mime(TopLevel::Text, SubLevel::EventStream, vec![])));
    headers.set(CacheControl(vec![CacheDirective::NoCache]));

    println!("{:?}", req);

    let mut count = 0;
    loop {
        let mut response = Response::with((iron::status::Ok, format!("data: Count!:{}", count)));
        response.headers = headers.clone();
        return Ok(response); //obviously won't do what I want

        count += 1;
        std::thread::sleep_ms(1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the short answer is: *you can't*. The current version of Iron is built on a single request-response interaction. This can be seen in your code because the only way to send a response is to return it; terminating the handler thread.

There's an issue in Iron to [utilize the new async support in Hyper](https://github.com/iron/iron/issues/446), which itself was [merged relatively recently](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/395). There are even [other people trying to use Server-Send Events in Hyper](https://github.com/hyperium/hyper/issues/719) that haven't succeeded yet.

---

If you are willing to use the Hyper master branch, something like this seems to work. No guarantees that this is a *good* solution or that it doesn't eat up all your RAM or CPU. It seems to work in Chrome though.

```
extern crate hyper;

use std::time::{Duration, Instant};
use std::io::prelude::*;

use hyper::{Control, Encoder, Decoder, Next };
use hyper::server::{Server, HandlerFactory, Handler, Request, Response};
use hyper::status::StatusCode;
use hyper::header::ContentType;
use hyper::net::{HttpStream};


fn main() {
    let address = "0.0.0.0:7777".parse().expect("Invalid address");
    let server = Server::http(&address).expect("Invalid server");

    let (_listen, server_loop) = server.handle(MyFactory).expect("Failed to handle");

    println!("Starting...");
    server_loop.run();
}


struct MyFactory;

impl HandlerFactory<HttpStream> for MyFactory {
    type Output = MyHandler;

    fn create(&mut self, ctrl: Control) -> Self::Output {
        MyHandler {
            control: ctrl,
        }
    }
}


struct MyHandler {
    control: Control,
}

impl Handler<HttpStream> for MyHandler {
    fn on_request(&mut self, _request: Request<HttpStream>) -> Next {
        println!("A request was made");
        Next::write()
    }

    fn on_request_readable(&mut self, _request: &mut Decoder<HttpStream>) -> Next {
        println!("Request has data to read");
        Next::write()
    }

    fn on_response(&mut self, response: &mut Response) -> Next {
        println!("A response is ready to be sent");

        response.set_status(StatusCode::Ok);
        let mime = "text/event-stream".parse().expect("Invalid MIME");
        response.headers_mut().set(ContentType(mime));

        every_duration(Duration:: from_secs(1), self.control.clone());

        Next::wait()
    }

    fn on_response_writable(&mut self, response: &mut Encoder<HttpStream>) -> Next {
        println!("A response can be written");

        // Waited long enough, send some data
        let fake_data = r#"event: userconnect
data: {"username": "bobby", "time": "02:33:48"}"#;

        println!("Writing some data");
        response.write_all(fake_data.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write");
        response.write_all(b"\n\n").expect("Failed to write");

        Next::wait()
    }
}

use std::thread;

fn every_duration(max_elapsed: Duration, control: Control) {
    let mut last_sent: Option<Instant> = None;
    let mut count = 0;

    thread::spawn(move || {
        loop {
            // Terminate after a fixed number of messages
            if count >= 5 {
                println!("Maximum messages sent, ending");
                control.ready(Next::end()).expect("Failed to trigger end");
                return;
            }

            // Wait a little while between messages
            if let Some(last) = last_sent {
                let elapsed = last.elapsed();
                println!("It's been {:?} since the last message", elapsed);

                if elapsed < max_elapsed {
                    let remaining = max_elapsed - elapsed;
                    println!("There's {:?} remaining", remaining);
                    thread::sleep(remaining);
                }
            }

            // Trigger a message
            control.ready(Next::write()).expect("Failed to trigger write");

            last_sent = Some(Instant::now());
            count += 1;
        }
    });
}
```

And the client-side JS:

```
var evtSource = new EventSource("http://127.0.0.1:7777");

evtSource.addEventListener("userconnect", function(e) {
    const obj = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log(obj);
}, false);
```